# Image won't load to template in Django, but is stored to Media file

Tags: django, image, django-models, media, django-urls

I'm trying to get a posted image to display on a Listview Blog application.

### Models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Post_images',null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    success_url = "post-detail"
    template_name = 'post_form.html'
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

### home.html

```
{% extends "blog/blogbase.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
         {% if Post.image %}
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
           {% else %}
           <span class="text-muted">No cover</span>
           {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I see "No cover printed" on all of the posts indicatign that Post.image is not registering.

### settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I think it has to do with the media root, because when I upload the image it saves to the media file.  I think the html/urls/settings connection is messed up.

Comment: in your HTML, change `{% if Post.image %}` with `{% if post.image %}`. `post` != `Post`.

Comment: You should be using `post.image` instead of `Post.image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in these lines in the template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
         {% if Post.image %}
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
           {% else %}
           <span class="text-muted">No cover</span>
           {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

In your second line, you have capitalized `post` from your for loop. It should be `post.image`, not `Post.image`.

The complete fixed code:

```
{% extends "blog/blogbase.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
         {% if post.image %}
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
           {% else %}
           <span class="text-muted">No cover</span>
           {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you! Its super confusing that it's capitalized in models, but not here.  the image still doesn't display correctly, but at least I get the indication that there is an image.

Comment: No problem. If this resolves this issue, hit the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: In template, `post ` is not a model, but rather an instance of a model. You are an instance of a human. The model is the template for the species.